# I want to sort the data based on concatenated columns

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this code

```
$this->db->select("*")->from("events")->join("employees" , "events.event_manager_id = employees.employee_id")->where('events.status' , 1)->order_by(concat('events.event_start_date'.' '.'events.event_start_time','desc'));
```

event_start_date is in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` and event_start_time is in `hh:mm:ss`

I want to sort the data based on concatenated event_start_date and event_start_time but this is giving me an error. Any ideas?

Comment: which error you can see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've no idea why you want to use concat here.
What about this ?

```
$this->db
    ->select("*")
    ->from("events")
    ->join("employees" , "events.event_manager_id = employees.employee_id")
    ->where('events.status' , 1)
    ->order_by("events.event_start_date",'desc');
    ->order_by("events.event_start_time",'desc');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate columns in database for date and time, then you can do something like this

```
$this->db->query('select * from events where event_manager_id = "employee_id" order by event_start_date desc ,event_start_time desc');
```